# contact form 7 - cannot run php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form

I have installed WordPress and the plugin `contact form 7` in it.

To make it a multi-page contact form I have installed `Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms` as well.
Everything works fine until yet. Even the mail gets sent.

The problem I am having is, that I want to run some PHP-code before the emails get sent.

I have inserted this code to try the ability of the plugin to run it.

```
function testfunc( $cf7 )
{
    mysql_connect("localhost", "user_name", "password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `aaaaaaaaaaa` ( test VARCHAR(30))");
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'testfunc', 1);
```

The function even works fine when I run it outside of the plugin in an extra php-file.

Now I cannot figure out why the function does not work when inserted in the plugin?

Comment: have you checked if the table `aaaaaaaaaaa` already exists?

Comment: yes, that is what i want to achieve and thats how I know it is not working, because the table does not exist after running the script

Comment: try adding `or die(mysql_error());` after `mysql_query`.

Comment: the problem is i do not even get any responses from the server like this. i do not get anything back because I am runnnig this whole thing in wordpress while submitting a form.

Comment: Is the parameter $cf7 mandatory? That could be the issue.

Comment: Please read [Why shouldnt I use mysql_*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/434949)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**wordpress create tabel using this way not in php structure for connect:**

[More info hear for create, get table data for wp](http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-custom-tables-wordpress-plugin-activation)

```
function testfunc( $cf7 )
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tablename';

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$table_name."(
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Query database in wordpress using it's global `wpdb` object like this way

### [Refer this](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb#query_-_Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database)

```
function testfunc( $cf7 )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE `aaaaaaaaaaa` ( test VARCHAR(30))");
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'testfunc', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Rave Patel

I only suggest that you check if the table exists before trying to create it everytime.

```
function testfunc( $cf7 )
{

    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'tablename';

    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
            UNIQUE KEY id (id)
        )";

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }
}
```